# Webshims: validate form when submitting via click on a link

Tags: html, forms, validation, polyfills, webshim

I am using the Webshims library for polyfilling the validation of a HTML5 form. The problem is that in order for the validation to kick in I have to use an input submit button. This is something that I wish to avoid, since I have a css-styled "linkbutton" for the purpose of saving the form:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" class="submit">
    <em>&nbsp;</em><span>Save form</span>
</a>
```

When clicking the "linkbutton" the form submits fine, but the validation never occurs. I use jQuery to submit the form when clicking the link:

```
$('myLink').click(function(e) {
    $('myForm').submit();
});
```

Is it possible to someway force the validation to occur the same way as when submitting the form with a input submit button?

Comment: I understand your problem (although I don't know the cause of it), but is there any reason you don't want to just use a styled `<button>` to submit the form? You can make them look exactly like regular links. What is your code that sets up the validation polyfill (if any), that could be the issue? Sorry, haven't used that library so I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use a button, because we're having design guidelines for consistent looking linkbuttons, and I have to break those in order to make the <button> appear like the linkbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webshims implements the form validation API as specified by HTML5. You can read the following bugreport and my answer to it: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/issues/103#issuecomment-4298458

Here is a short "workaround" for your problem:

```
//configure webshims to use customized bubbles
$.webshims.setOptions('forms', {
    replaceValidationUI: true
});

//start polyfilling forms feature
$.webshims.polyfill('forms');


$(function(){
    $('myLink').click(function(e) {
        if($('myForm').checkValidity()){
            $('myForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

But to make this clear, the best way is to use submit buttons. To get submit buttons styled, here is a simple button reset, which should work x-browser:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input.btn-reset,
button.btn-reset {
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #000;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I understand that the best way is to use submit buttons, but this is not achievable in my case.